# In Powershell file, catch few exceptions and ignore few exceptions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script file and some module files. Till now there was no exception handling done in these files. I have to do them. Say for example this is the sample ps1 file I have.

```
# Add the App-ppol identity to the Administrators group
$Computer    = $env:computername
$AppPoolUserRunas =  $NewServiceAccountName
$AppPoolUser = $NewServiceAccountName -replace "\\", "/"
([ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://$AppPoolUser").path)

SomeotherCommand here 2
Someother command here 3
.
.
.
```

For this I'm trying to implement try catch. So I have done something like this.

```
try
{

# Add the App-ppol identity to the Administrators group
$Computer    = $env:computername
$AppPoolUserRunas =  $NewServiceAccountName
$AppPoolUser = $NewServiceAccountName -replace "\\", "/"
([ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators,group").psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://$AppPoolUser").path)  # say this as command 1

SomeotherCommand here 2
Someother command here 3
.
.
.
}
Catch
{
   write-output "Error in File1: $_.Exception.Message" 
}
```

Now what this is doing is, for every exception, it is terminating the execution. Say suppose I want to ignore some exceptions, like the first command gives an exception, if the user is already in appPool. I need to ignore such exceptions and continue. But I want it to write on the console though.

Is there any possible way to do this? Say I have 5 commands getting executed in a file.

Command 1 : Continue even the exception occurs.
Command 2 : Catch the exception and stop the execution.
Command 3 : Catch the exception and stop the execution.
Command 4 : Continue even the exception occurs.
Command 5 : Catch and terminate.

Comment: generally speaking, you want to have your try/catch wrapped around ONE error source. [*grin*] then you can do as you please with each one ... and _deal_ with them in detail instead of in general.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, you are suggesting me to wrap each command in try catch , is it?

Comment: yes, wrap each thing you want to catch the errors from in its own test. some things - like path testing - can be done with a simple IF. for things that you are not sure how they may go wrong - or if they can go wrong in multiple ways - use a try/catch. if you read up on that construct you will see that you can have multiple catches for each possible failure point. [*grin*] each catch can test for the error type ... it can be quite flexible if you need to get that complicated.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]